# Kali Linux: Unable to install chromium or firefox on Raspberry Pi

Tags: software-installation, web-browsers, kali

When I try to install Chromium or Firefox, the following error occurs:

```
$ sudo apt-get install chromium-browser
E: Package 'chromium-browser' has no installation candidate

$ sudo apt-get install firefox-mozilla-build
E: Unable to locate package firefox-mozilla-build
```

Info about the system
$ hostnamectl

```
Static hostname: kali
         Icon name: computer
        Machine ID: ----
           Boot ID: ----
  Operating System: Kali GNU/Linux Rolling
            Kernel: Linux 4.19.93-Re4son-v7+
      Architecture: arm
```

How would I go about installing Chromium and Firefox?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, run the following command to update the repos and update your packages:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade
```

To install chromium:

```
sudo apt install chromium
```

To install firefox:

```
sudo apt install firefox
```

Comment: Please note that you should [better use `apt full-upgrade`](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/raspbian/updating.md) instead of only simple `apt upgrade`.

Comment: Ah sorry! I’ll edit that in my answer.

Comment: @Ingo done apt full-update still getting the same error

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

```
apt full-upgrade
apt-get install -y gconf-service libasound2 libatk1.0-0 libcairo2 libcups2 libfontconfig1 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libnspr4 libpango-1.0-0 libxss1 fonts-liberation libappindicator1 libnss3 lsb-release xdg-utils
wget http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/c/chromium/chromium_81.0.4044.92-1_armel.deb
dpkg -i chromium_81.0.4044.92-1_armhf.deb; apt-get -fy install
```

Make sure to run those commands as root.

Comment: dpkg: error processing archive chromium_81.0.4044.92-1_armhf.deb (--install):
 package architecture (armhf) does not match system (armel)

Comment: I am using PI 3

Comment: Ok, I edited it; give the new version a try.